# scripts requested via systemjs fail with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, tfs, angular, systemjs

I'm building a [hub extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/get-started/node) for Team Foundation Server 2015.

My Hub HTML page works fine until I switch over to use [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) and angular2, at which point any script request coming from systemjs appears to be rejected with a 401 unauthorized.

I followed the [Angular2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) guide closely and it all works fine locally without authentication.

But once I upload my application to TFS, any script requested by systemjs is rejected as seen below:

```
Error: XHR error (401 Unauthorized) loading http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/my-publisher/extension/source-extensions/1.1.2/assetbyname/scripts/main.js(…)

Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publishRejection @ angular2-polyfills.js:401
(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123
Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
```

If I load my scripts via a script tag, there's no authorization issue. But when I do it via systemjs like this, it fails with the 401 error:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      scripts: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('scripts/main.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

My question is this: When using systemjs to load scripts rather than loading them directly, is there something extra I have to do to avoid getting 401 unauthorized?

Comment: This sounds to me a configuration in your server not in angular 2

Comment: Remember that the script loads fine without systemjs, but receives a 401 unauthorized when loaded by systemjs. That should make it a client-side issue rather than a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemJS will use XHR to load code, which may somehow be the difference here.

If you want SystemJS to use <script> tag injection, try:

```
  System.config({
    packages: {
      scripts: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        scriptLoad: true
      }
    }
  });
```

If it still happens with that, then it must be server configuration for sure.

Comment: That got me further... I added scriptLoad: true and then the script was loaded successfully without getting a 401 error. So this did fix the 401 auth issue, so thank you for that! But I immediately got the error [Uncaught TypeError: Unexpected anonymous System.register call](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/861)

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1150) for a continuation of the conversation and the solution.

Comment: I'm a bit late on this but I think that bloating up the DOM with script tags is not an ideal solution. I would much more appreciate a solution making the default SystemJS XHR mode to work.